# C++ Python bindings sizes

Tags: python, c++, boost, binding, metrics

I read that binaries created with [Boost.Python are bloated](https://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-did-you-switch-from-boost-python-to-shiboken). Does anybody has real data (ideally reproducible) on exact sizes of C++ bindings for Python created with different frameworks (plain Python and Boost at minimum)?

The list of known C++/Python binding frameworks - [Python/C++ Binding Library comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492755/python-c-binding-library-comparison)